# How do I encode and decode a geoTiff file from a base64string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gdal, geotiff

I have a geotiff file that is being converted to a base64string upon being selected. The encoded file is then uploaded to an ASP.NET web service and then decoded and saved with a .tiff extension. The problem is that the metadata within the file is significantly altered from the original file.

JavaScript

```
       var fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onloadend = function () {
            var base64string = fr.result;
            var imgStr = base64string.split("base64,")[1];
            App.instance.client.area.uploadMap(imgStr);
        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(value.rawFile);
```

C#/ASP.NET Web API:

```
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(mapImage);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I'm then extrating the metadata uploaded image with the GDAL library. The image looks fine, but the metadata contained within the file is completely different. The corner coordinates are no longer accurate and there is color table information in the new file, which wasn't present in the original.

Is there any way to handle this conversion so that the bytes aren't altered?

Comment: something is not right at all; the file should be identical on both ends... where does value.rawFile come from?

Comment: I'm using a kendo file upload control and uploading the file when the onSelect event is triggered. Value.rawFile contains information about the file object:
Here is what is contained in value.rawFile:
File
lastModified: 1419272156000
lastModifiedDate: Mon Dec 22 2014 10:15:56 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
name: "out.tif"
size: 691795
type: "image/tiff"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File

Comment: don't know if this helps, but everything shown looks fine. i would guess that the GDAL lib is screwing up. copy the file from the server upload folder (if any, if not dump it for this) then open it using the same app as the orig. if they match, GDAL sucks.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. I've tried using a file comparer as well and the binary content of the files is different, weird.

Comment: the only other possibility i can see is the App.instance.client.area.uploadMap part, maybe it rewrites the image somehow. the regular FileReader stuff looks ok. maybe the server Image interface adjusts the image, but if you looked at the server-side value before that part, then it must be the uploadMap tool.

Comment: Thanks for the further suggestions, dandavis. I was able to solve the problem, when I was saving the uploaded file to disk, the file metadata was being altered and gdal was doing its best to piece together the metadata, which was inaccurate since the file had changed. So instead, I saved the geotiff using File.WriteAllBytes() and everything worked. Thanks for your help!